# My image sitemaps have no URL’s of my images

Tags: xml, wordpress, image, seo, sitemap

I have a lot of images and infographics on my site but they are not being found on search engines. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Here’s my link https://muthusblog.com/
This XML sitemap contains 0 URLs that’s the problem https://muthusblog.com/attachment-sitemap.xml
If you search site:muthusblog.com and search on images you will find just one image but there are more than 40 that aren’t showing that’s the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a related issue with the number of images showing in Yoast sitemap.xml, so when the blog post originally contains 4 images for example.
On the sitemap.xml image display "1" which is the featured image just.
Or it can **display "0" if you didn't add the featured image.**
I think this problem can affect your SEO.
So after trying different things.
In my case, I found that when I copy images directly to the WordPress blog post or page editor, Yoast will not take that image as an original post image.
Until you Upload the image to your library and add it to the blog post editor.
So if you are creating your post outside Wodrpess like Google Docs for example, then you copy the whole blog post with all images directly to your WordPress editor.
Images will not show up on the sitemap.
**You have to upload them to your website**, then add them to your post from the website library using WordPress editor.